# Once replaced, skip that part of string - Regex Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

I expect a string of just numbers from HTML inputbox but i am looking for a regex so that i can capture some part of string and replace it with something and now what i want is, for next iteration, regex should skip part which has been processed.

Take a look at my regex

```
string.replace(/([\d]{10})/gm, "$1,")
```

Expected results for iterations

1. 895645784578457845784578457845 `source`
2. 8956457845,7845784578,4578457845,9089 `more data is coming`

But problem is result

1. 8956457845,7845784578,4578457845
2. 8956457845,,,7845784578,,,4578457845,,,9089

Comment: [Works for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/ouey9bzn/) `"895645784578457845784578457845".replace(/([\d]{10})/gm, "$1,")` returns `"8956457845,7845784578,4578457845,"` as one would expect.

Comment: Side note: `[\d]` is just a long way to write `\d`. :-)

Comment: probably you;d like to use negative lookahead `/(\d{10}(?!\,))/gm`, like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bw0p5k4z/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you'd like to apply regex-replace for one numerical string recursely like `string.replace(\regex\, '$1,').replace(\regex\, '$1,').replace(\regex\, '$1,')`, but ignored the parts which already replaced.

Below is one solution which uses **negative lookahead**.

```js
let test = '895645784578457845784578457845' //org string
let test1 = test.replace(/(\d{10}(?!\,))/gm, "$1,")
                .replace(/(\d{10}(?!\,))/gm, "$1,")
                .replace(/(\d{10}(?!\,))/gm, "$1,") 
                // simulate recurse-replace three times
console.log(test1)

test1 += '1234567890123' //new string came
let test2 = test1.replace(/(\d{10}(?!\,))/gm, "$1,")
console.log(test2)

test2 += '1234567890123' //new string came
let test3 = test2.replace(/(\d{10}(?!\,))/gm, "$1,")
console.log(test3)
```